# MariaDb 10.3 persistent column derived from timestamp

Tags: mariadb

Currently I am using MariaDB 10.1. I have tables with persistent columns that derive the `date` value from a timestamp. I understand this is no longer possible in MariaDB 10.3.

> ... `dataDt` date AS (date(from_unixtime(`timestamp_int`))) PERSISTENT,

How can I do the same in MariaDB 10.3?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here is the cause: [MDEV-21593](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-21593). A possible workaround: `Non-deterministic built-in functions are supported in expressions for not indexed VIRTUAL generated columns.`, see [Generated (Virtual and Persistent/Stored) Columns :: Expression Support](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/#expression-support).

Comment: I did read about the cause. But really only reason I would add a column to a table is to make index. in my case, it is faster when using `.. where dt='yyyy-mm-dd' ` rather than using ` ... where timestamp_int between unix_timestamp( 'yyyy-mm-dd') and unix_timestamp( 'yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59')`

Comment: Let's see the `SELECT` and `EXPLAIN`.  We may have another workaround.